# How to show gridview rows as links?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridView . .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAll" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind. .

```
protected void BindGrid()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmdBind = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Department, Year FROM UserProfile",conn);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdBind.ExecuteReader();
        GridAll.DataSource = reader;
        GridAll.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

It works fine. . .
Now I want that grid view show all rows as link so that clicking on link show more details. .

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You want the text in each cell of the row to be a hyperlink that shows more detail? What is the "more detail" and how should the detail be shown? Another row? A popup? You need to provide much more detail on what it is that you want. This site is not intended to be a request site for "here is my idea, code it up for me". This site provides help for issues, but only after you have done some research and detailed what you have tried. You have done the minimal amount of effort and are just asking someone else to do your work.

Comment: @Karl: More details are some other fields from the table that I want to show on different page. . I am just asking for some hints here as I mentioned I am new to programming

Comment: Okay, do you know the difference between a BoundField and a TemplateField in a GridView?

Comment: @Karl: Yes, little bit

Comment: The TemplateField allows you to build various types of UI controls within a cell (link, drop down list, etc.). As the answer below shows you need to build a LinkButton that get its text from a field in the data returned from your query to the database. GridView has many events, one of importance here is the RowDataBound event, this fires for every row that is put into the GridView, here is where you can setup the unique values for each link you will have in the GridView (i.e. each link will point to the same page, but have different query string).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do it using `GridView` Template Field:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
         <HeaderTemplate>
           Link
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Value" )%>' Text='<%# Eval("Value" )%>'
                   ID="lnk" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Where value the link that you want to put. You can do the same from code behind as well:

```
protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Customer cust = e.Row.DataItem as Customer;
            if (!cust.ShowURL)
            {
                LinkButton lnkWebURL = e.Row.FindControl("lnk") as LinkButton;
                //Set lnkWebURL stugg
            }
        }
    }
```

I copied this answer from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/249541/how-to-make-my-entire-gridview-row-to-have-hyperli).